# Apache Authentication - Find out user password

Tags: apache-2.2, sudo, user-accounts

My field of expertise is far away from server management but I am currently covering for a former collegue of mine, so I apologize in advance if my question doesn't make sense.

I have to restart an Apache server running on Debian. However, I do not have the password for the root user, nor for the user that I am logged in as currently( let's call it user X). I was given the SSL certificates which are now installed on my local machine and I use SuperPutty to connect to the server without username-password credentials. However, everytime I type a command with "sudo", I am prompted to type the password for user X.It might be of relevance to say that user X has Admin permissions.

My question is:

Is there a way to find out the user X password either from the SSL certificates or from the server files? or

Is there a way to find the root user password while I am logged in as user X? or

Is there another way to log in as root user?

I tried:

- reading the password from the htpasswd file - the file is strongly encripted.
- changing the password using the htpasswd command - no success.
- guessing  the password - no success.
- creating a new user - no permissions.

Comment: unless one of the certificates you were give allows you to log in as root. there's no way to to enable `sudo` access other than guessing the user password.

Answer (score 0):

No.

First of all, you're not looking for an Apache password stored in a .htaccess file. You're looking for the *Linux* user password. That's stored in `/etc/shadow`, which you can't even read. And it's salted and stored using a good hashing algorithm.

The certificates does not contain the password. They are merely an alternate way of authenticating via SSH. `sudo` will however *not* accept those.

Ask the owner of the system to create an user account for you with a known password that you can change afterwards.

Comment: Thank you so much! This gives me a direction forward.